# Loop over children of nodes recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a challenge looping over an array's objects that have nested children properties, the structure is like so

The traversing I have tried is not even close, I actually want the results to be an array that is flat

```
[{
element: 'a',
key: 'a',
isCollapsible: true,
isClickable: false,
children: [{
  element: 'a-1',
  key: 'a-1',
  indentChildren: false,
  children: [{
    element: 'a-1-1',
    key: 'a-1-1',
    children: [],
  }, {
    element: 'a-1-2',
    key: 'a-1-2',
    children: [],
  }],
}, {
  element: 'a-2',
  key: 'a-2',
  indentChildren: false,
  children: [{
    element: 'a-2-1',
    key: 'a-2-1',
    indentChildren: false,
    children: [{
      element: 'a-2-1-1',
      key: 'a-2-1-1',
      children: [],
    }],
  }, {
    element: 'a-2-2',
    key: 'a-2-2',
    children: [],
  }, {
    element: 'a-2-3',
    key: 'a-2-3',
    children: [],
  }],
}],
}]
```

Comment: Please reivew the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197 Only you may want to change {} to array and add just elements to that array without keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ES6 you might use a generator with nested yield to flatten the iteration:

```
 function* flatten(array){
   for(const el of array){
     yield el;
     yield* flatten(el.children);
   }
}
```

So you can do:

```
 for(const el of flatten(yourdata)){
    //...
 }
```

Comment: Wow! this has to be one of the best days in my life, I won't ever forget this day :D, @Jonas, thanks so much, it works

Comment: @teebo youre welcome, glad to help :) Please also read [this in depth wiki on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: that's so elegant!